# Generating Random Number From Discontinuous Distribution Function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I have the following density function :

[image]

I want to generate random variate from this density function according to acceptance-rejection algorithm , Inverse transform algorithm and composition method . How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation of these methods? They can be easily found on the internet. http://web.ics.purdue.edu/~hwan/IE680/Lectures/Chap08Slides.pdf

Comment: Please give acceptence-rejection algorithm for this particular problem .